# How can I load fonts in my entire project expo?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

According to the expo documentation we have two ways to load fonts into a component.
Way # 1:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

export default function App() {
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    Montserrat: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat.ttf'),
  });
  
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 30 }}>Montserrat</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Way #2:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fontsLoaded: false,
  };

  async loadFonts() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      // Load a font `Montserrat` from a static resource
      Montserrat: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat.ttf'),

      // Any string can be used as the fontFamily name. Here we use an object to provide more control
      'Montserrat-SemiBold': {
        uri: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
        display: Font.FontDisplay.FALLBACK,
      },
    });
    this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadFonts();
  }

  render() {
    // Use the font with the fontFamily property after loading
    if (this.state.fontsLoaded) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Default Font</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20 }}>Montserrat</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', fontSize: 20 }}>
            Montserrat-SemiBold
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

As you can see in the documentation with the link below:
[Font expo documentation] (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/)

The question is ... is there any way to reuse this shipment?
Why this repetition of code in all components that need custom fonts seems to me a waste of time and a window for the disorganization of the code.

Comment: Children of the component that loaded the fonts will have access to those fonts